# como puedo generar copias incrementales con Tar en Linux?

Tags: linux, script, tar

necesito generar copias diarias incrementales de una carpeta con Tar. con incremental me refiero a que luego de la primera vez que se cree la copia, solo se agreguen los archivos nuevos o modificados a la copia anterior, es decir, mantener la copia de seguridad actualizada.

Ejemplo: necesito generar la copia incremental de Carpeta1, entonces lo que intente es lo siguiente:

```
tar --update -f /backup/customBackup/backup.tar /home/Carpeta1/ > /var/log/TarLogs/Carpeta1.log 2>&1
```

el problema que tuve es que la primera vez que se genero el backup.tar pesaba 68 GB (lo cual esta bien) ya que mas o menos ese es el peso de Carpeta1, pero el siguiente dia cuando se ejecuto de nuevo el script (se esta ejecutando en el Cron de Linux), el archivo backup.tar peso 127 GB, es decir, no se actualizo sino que casi duplico su peso, como si se hubiese creado otra copia dentro. Que estoy haciendo mal? alguien puede ayudarme?

Answer (score 2):

Creo que tendrias que probar a usar la funcionalida de tar para copias incrementales descrita en gnu tar:

```
sudo tar --create --file=/backup/customBackup/backup.tar --listed-incremental=/var/log/carpeta1.snar /home/Carpeta1
```

----EDITADO------

Otra forma podría ser usar --level=0 de la siguiente manera

```
sudo tar -g /var/log/custbackup --level=0 -cvpf /backup/customBackup/backup.tar /home/Carpeta1
```

Puedes obtener mas informacion sobre como realizar las recuperaciones en el siguiente articulo de gnu tar:

http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Incremental-Dumps.html

Comment: Lo intenté con con el comando -g el cual en primera instancia crea un backup completo y un archivo aparte donde se almancenas las modificaciones posteriores, lo que no me gusta es que me crea una carpeta aparte por cada modificación, es decir, hoy hice la copia de seguridad, y mañana hago una modificación y luego la copia de seguridad, pues entonces me crea una carpeta con dentro del .Tar con sólo las modificaciones que se hicieron la última vez. No habría una forna de que todo se mezcle en el mismo .Tar?

Comment: podrías usar una estrategia de concatenado de ficheros tar con -A,--concatenate, lo que ya no tengo tan seguro es el tema de usarlo de forma conjunta con la solución de incrementales que expuse mas arriba dado que no se como se comportaria.

Comment: quizás podrías usar la opción --level=0, actualizo la respuesta

Comment: Lo que estoy pensando es volver a hacerlas con Rsync, pero lo que quiero hacer es generar el .tar.gz luego de crear la copia y que la copia que no esta comprimida se elimine para liberar espacio, y esto hacerlo a diario, ya que se me ocurre para resolver por ahora, xq tengo dias con esto y necesito generar copias de seguridad incrementales en mi servidor. como podria hacer para generar las copias en ese orden? 1 crear la copia con Rsync, 2 comprimir esa copia de seguridad (luego de verificar que se haya completado la copia sin errores) y por ultimo eliminar la copia que no esta comprimida?

Comment: Bueno, si ya usaste rsync sabes que necesitas poder comparar origen y destino para poder realizar el incremento, si estuviera comprimido el destino no podrias por lo que tendrias que elaborar un script que en primer lugar descomprimiese el ultimo backup efectuado, luego lanzar rsync y despues volver a comprimir. A efectos de backup y recuperacion creo que es mas atractivo y util poder tener versiones diferenciadas para poder rescatar en un punto en el tiempo, tambien podrias considerar si es critico, utilizar una herramienta gnu como bacula o similares.

Comment: yo ejecuto el comando de la siguiente manera: rsync /home/servicioweb/Escritorio/Prueba/ /backupRsync > /home/servicioweb/Escritorio/rsync.log . probe en mi computadora local y la copia la hace bien, si agrego algo despues al archivo original eso es lo unico que copia, asi que asumo que lo esta haciendo incremental, ya que en el log solo me muestra la creacion de los nuevos archivos.